# Can I import codestyles into Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have tried NetBeans for some time, but have not made my final move yet. I need to be able to import codestyle settings from Idea or Eclipse. Anyone know it that is possible? Or if some plugins allow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not such thing. You'll have to edit font and color settings in a hidden folder or create a plugin. Can IDEA import NetBeans color schemes, can Eclipse do the same?

Comment: No, your right. It's not usual to have such import feature. Guess I will invest some time in converting my styles manually.

Comment: On a related note, once you do get things configured in NetBeans, most of the configuration can be exported to a file (from the configuration dialog) which you can use to copy your settings to other NetBeans installs. This can be particularly useful when you install a new release of NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this covers all codestyle settings in your existing IDE (Eclipse) and future IDE (Netbeans) but you can define `.editorconfig` file to maintain consistent coding styles between different IDEs. It has plugins for all major IDEs. http://editorconfig.org/

Besides, it really helps you if you have other project members using various IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

For NetBeans 8.0 and 7.4 there is a experimental plugin to help on this matter. You can install it directly from the IDE searching for 'Eclipse Code Formatter for Java' or go to the webpage http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50877/eclipse-code-formatter-for-java and download the nbm file as needed. Be aware it is an experimental plugin, so use it carefully.