# Import code style settings from Intellij IDEA into NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea

There was a similar question a few years ago:
[Can I import codestyles into Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306890/can-i-import-codestyles-into-netbeans)

I wonder if sutiation have changed?

I didn't find a way to import code style settings (a separate XML file with code style settings) into NetBeans IDE. NetBeans settings import/export feature seems to be ignoring code style settings.

Comment: Any news on this one?

Comment: Unfortunately nope, I had to move settings manually. I guess its just not implemented in NetBeans.

Answer (score 3):

EditorConfig is a coding style standard, it's an configuration file that you can add to your project. You can find plugins for netbeans too, personally I never used it in Netbeans but you can give it a try.